# Laravel custom validation is not creating Eloquent object

Tags: laravel, validation

I have wrote a custom validation function.

```
function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    $request = Invitation::where('invitation_token', md5($value));

    if ($request === null) {
        $fail('Invitation Code is invalid.');    
    } elseif ($request->is_active === false) {
        $fail('This Invitation Code has been expired.');
    }
}
```

It give the error: `Property [is_active] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`
Why don't it is getting the `Invitation` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created the query, but you didn't run it.

In that case, you can pick up only the first item using `get()` method.

```
$request = Invitation::where('invitation_token', md5($value))->first();
```

Using this method will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Then shouldn’t it return null, if the query didn’t executed?

Comment: It will only return null, if you run the query and the item is not found, if not, it will return an instance of Eloquent Builder.